# JADE-LEAP congurations in Eclipse?

Tags: java, wurfl, agents-jade

I have 2 questions regarding JADE LEAP and WURFL repository as I am new in JADE.

1- Can any one tell me how do I configure JADE LEAP in Eclipse. I downloaded JADE-LEAP addOn but didn't know how I configure ? I add simple jade.jar in my Eclipse project but I want to see mobile simulator in eclipse using JADE-Leap

2- How I create a WURFL agent which retreives property from repository or wurfl.xml file without using servlets?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://jade.tilab.com/papers-examples.htm

Download the "chat android" package and import it in eclipse (your eclipse must be configured for android developing), it should have no problems compiling.

With that code and the "Jade Android Tutorial" (same link) you should be able to understand the basic on how to use jade on android.